# Meteor CollectionFS adding images on the server

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to get CollectionFS to work storing some images in my app. I've found the example apps really good at showing how to use the package on the client, but I'm having absolutely no success trying to work out how to store some initial images from the server in a start-up function (adds some dummy data to the various collections I'm using for seeding the data).

I basically want to grab an image from the public folder on the server, punch that into the collection and then retrieve it as I would normally on the client.

Can someone point me in the right direction to get this started, I think I'm missing something fundamental here.

Thanks.

Comment: I have never tried this but I guess you would use `storeBuffer` to do this (https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#store-a-file-from-the-server). Maybe in combination with a JS `FileReader`. Have you tried this?

Comment: This is basically what I've been trying to get going Tobold (sorry, should have been more specific) but am struggling to work out how it all hangs together on the server side. Any examples would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Looking further at the docs, I guess the bit I'm missing in the "Store a File From the Server" example, is how to make the buffer for an image that is already on disk. I guess it should be easy, but the process completely alludes me at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a small example that works. What I did step-by-step:

**1.** Grabbed [this](https://github.com/mxab/cfsfileurl-example) example, added the collectionFS package and updated to Meteor 0.7.0.1:

```
git clone https://github.com/mxab/cfsfileurl-example.git
cd cfsfileurl-example
mrt add collectionFS
meteor update
```

**2.** Created the public folder (`cfsfileurlexample/public/`) and copied an image `foo.jpg` into it.

**3.** Changed  `Meteor.startup` in `cfsfileurlexample/cfsfileurl-example.js` to look like this:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    var fs = Npm.require('fs');

    fs.readFile(process.env.PWD+'/public/foo.jpg', 
        Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (err, data) {
          if (err) throw err;
            //prints buffer
            //console.log(data);
            Images.storeBuffer('foo.jpg', data, { 
                contentType: 'image/jpg',
                encoding: 'binary'
            });
        },
        function(e){
            throw e;
        }));
});
```

**4.**  **Done**.

Whenever meteor restarts the image is added to the Images collectionFS and is displayed in the list of images.

**Notes**

One hacky thing might be the use of `process.env.PWD` to find the project directory (I first tried `process.cwd()` but apparently it points to somewhere else since meteor 0.6.5.). I tested in development and production mode but not after bundling the app. If you google for `meteor public folder path` you'll find some other discussions and solutions.

If you don't wrap the callback that you pass to `fs.readFile` using `Meteor.bindEnvironment` you'll get `Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.`

Comment: My goodness Tobold.. that is fantastic. You are a life saver.